# Linked servers: Transaction context in use by another session

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, linked-server

I'm using linked servers to perform some queries in a distributed transaction. It doesn't work in a distributed transaction. I get the following error:

> Transaction context in use by another session.

Not even this simplified example will work:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT server_id from sys.servers WHERE name = 'SomeServer')
BEGIN
       EXEC sp_dropserver  @server = N'SomeServer';
END

EXEC sp_addlinkedserver 
   @server = N'SomeServer',
   @srvproduct = N'',
   @provider = N'SQLNCLI',
   @datasrc = N'localhost';

EXEC sp_serveroption
       @server = N'SomeServer', 
       @optname = 'rpc out',
       @optvalue = 'on';
GO


BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRAN;

EXEC('SELECT TOP 100 * FROM [SomeServer].[SomeDatabase].dbo.tblFoo')

ROLLBACK;

EXEC sp_dropserver  @server = N'SomeServer';
```

Removing the work distributed, or removing the begin/rollback tran entirely also works. Running [sp_whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com) returns no rows. I have had to restart the server (on my laptop) several times because there were distributed transactions I was unable to kill even if I killed all the spids returned by sp_whoisactive.

In those possible related instances, killing thos spids more then once gives me:

> SPID X: transaction rollback in progress. Estimated rollback completion: 0%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188716.aspx

> Loopback linked servers cannot be used in a distributed transaction. Trying a distributed query against a loopback linked server from within a distributed transaction causes an error, such as error 3910: "[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Transaction context in use by another session." This restriction does not apply when an INSERT...EXECUTE statement, issued by a connection that does not have multiple active result sets (MARS) enabled, executes against a loopback linked server. Note that the restriction still applies when MARS is enabled on a connection.

Answer (score 1):

what are you trying to do? for most simple data retrievals from linked servers you don't need to start a distributed tran. it shouldn't effect your ability to roolback a tran if that's what you're worried about. so just say "BEGIN TRANSACTION"

Comment: I will need a distributed transaction here because I will be modifying tables on both the local server and the linked server.

Comment: hmm, that's too bad. I always try to avoid DTC because it is so finicky and sometimes buggy. there are many attractive alternatives including CLR and service broker.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and decided to change from using "4-part names" to "3-part names" when accessing local resources over a loopback linked server. I found this information in [this article](https://danieladeniji.wordpress.com/2014/01/21/technical-microsoft-sql-server-transact-sql-linked-server-error-transaction-context-in-use-by-another-session-msg-3910-level-16-state-2-line-1/) by Daniel Adeniji, where he says:

> The reason for the failure is that “Distributed Transactions”, the underlying infrastructure that co-ordinates transaction management only works when objects referenced via 4 part names are actually remote.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using SQL 2005 and got "transaction context in use by another session" when running Insert....exec over a linked server. The fix for me was to patch from SP2 build 3161 to SP3. SP2 cumulative 5 is supposed to fix though.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/947486